# Problems with IF EXISTS()

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, exists

When I try to run update a credit card type by passing in the @ID and @Name I get an error that says:

```
Msg 2786, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_SaveCreditCardType, Line 29
The data type of substitution parameter 1 does not match the expected type of the format specification.
```

The problem is with my piece of code that checks for the existence of the id in the CreditCardTypes table using this statement:

```
-- make sure the ID is a valid number
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CreditCardTypes WHERE ID = @ID)
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR('The Credit Card ID ''%s'' does not exist. Update Failed.', 15, 1, @ID)
                RETURN -100
            END
```

Does anyone have any idea why this may be giving me an error? I have seen many examples of using the the if exists() in this way, but for some reason it's giving me an error.

Here is the entire proc.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_SaveCreditCardType 
(
@ID int = null, 
@Name varchar(50),
@Description varchar(150) = null 
)
AS

DECLARE 
@Err INT

BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON 

-- check to make sure a Name was passed in
IF @Name IS NULL
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('A Name was not specified. Execution aborted.', 15, 1, @Name)
        RETURN -100
    END

-- check to see if an ID is passed
IF @ID IS NOT NULL AND @ID <> 0
    BEGIN
        -- make sure the ID is a valid number
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CreditCardTypes WHERE ID = @ID)
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR('The Credit Card ID ''%s'' does not exist. Update Failed.', 15, 1, @ID)
                RETURN -100
            END

        -- update an existing credit card type
        UPDATE CreditCardTypes 
            SET Name = @Name, 
                [Description] = @Description
            WHERE ID = @ID
        SET @Err = @@ERROR
            IF @Err <> 0 GOTO ErrorHandler
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- first check to make sure the credit card type doesn't already exist
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CreditCardTypes WHERE Name = @Name)
            BEGIN
                -- insert a new credit card type
                INSERT INTO CreditCardTypes (Name, [Description])
                VALUES (@Name, @Description)

                SET @Err = @@ERROR
                    IF @Err <> 0 GOTO ErrorHandler
            END
        ELSE
            RAISERROR('The Credit Card Type ''%s'' already exists. Insert failed.', 15, 1, @Name)
            RETURN -100
    END

SET @Err = @@ERROR
    IF @Err <> 0 GOTO ErrorHandler
RETURN 0

ErrorHandler:
    RAISERROR('An error occured while saving the credit card type ''%s''', 16, 1, @Name) WITH LOG
    RETURN -100
END
GO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
RAISERROR('The Credit Card ID ''%s'' does not exist. Update Failed.', 15, 1, @ID)
```

To:

```
RAISERROR('The Credit Card ID ''%d'' does not exist. Update Failed.', 15, 1, @ID)
```

`%s` is used for substituting strings... but `%d` is the substitution parameter for ints.

[RAISERROR in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177497.aspx)

Comment: Oh my hell! You're awesome brother thanks for the help. That was exactly the problem.  Lesson learned.  Thanks man!